# REST api Bad Request file replace

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, office-365, rest

I'm using sharepoint REST api using JavaScript to replace a file in a doc library. Here is the url structure I'm using.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

props.webUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'" + props.listId.slice(1, -1) + "')/RootFolder/Files/Add(url=@filename,overwrite=true)?@filename='" + encodeURIComponent(props.file.get_name()) + "'"
```

This call is not working if my filename contains apostrophe (ex: Shekar's.pptx). The browser is rejecting the call and throwing Bad request error and showing message like

> The expression "web/lists(guid'cde87068-baf9-4863-910e-049bd7f3e04e')/RootFolder/Files/Add(Url='Shekar's.pptx',overwrite=true)" is not valid`.

I know the expression `'Shekar's.pptx'`is wrong. I tried to encode with `encodeUri`, `encodeUriComponent`, `escape` and `escapeProperly`- None of them worked, still getting the same error messsage. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Use two quotes. That is `'Shekar''s.pptx'`

Answer (score 1):

@Nadeem Yousuf is correct. You should escape it using either double quotes or by using `\`

Here is a little function you can use for that

```
function escapeApostrophe(title) {
    title = title.replace(/'/g, "''")
    return title
}
```